# HATEOAS backend?

Tags: react-admin, hateoas, admin-on-rest

I would like to use `react-admin` with my Restful HATEOAS inspired server.
Has anyone ever tried that?

Unfortunately, `react-admin` wants to work with id's and does not hand objects to the dataprovider. Especially in `getManyReference` it does not supply the referencing resource but only a fieldname (target) and an id. Is there any way to change that?

I have seen the hal implementation of a data provider and the graphql implementation. They grep an object's id from the "self" link which is basically perverting the whole idea of HATEOAS.

UPDATE: We now plan to slightly re-define the param `target`. It should contain a filter field name which together with param `id`can be used to filter for referenced resource. Instead of denoting a field-name, we give the name of the referencing resource in `target` so that the `dataprovider` can fetch the record of the referencing resource, containing the links to subresources. The `resource` field passed to `getManyReference` is then used as name of the link. We then extract the URL from the referencing record, append query parameters, and, with some luck, bob will be our uncle... Didn't try yet, just mentioning that we are doing some research here.

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` can be the string, you should make the `id` the entire absolute URL, because ultimately... in HATEOAS the URL *is* the globally unique id for any object.

Comment: i want the client to use the links provided by the server instead of generating urls based on ids. a user might have some files, so the user-response contains a link field called "files" with url = "/users/1/files". If i want the fetch files for a given user i do not want RA generate the link like "/users/{id}/files" but i want to use the link in the original user record. But i only get the id of that user record in the DataProvider.